# How to remove blanks from autofilter column using vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am preparing some reports which require filtering data from one sheet to another. I used VBA for automating this process. However, I am facing an issue in filtering. Just wanted to exclude blank row using Auto Filter. The below code includes the code to filter However, I want the opposite of the following code.

```
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Revenue Summary").Range("$K$4:$P$" & lastr)
.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="="
```

Answer (score 2):

In the criteria argument you need to use this:

```
.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="<>"
```

not this:

```
.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="="
```